# how to deactivate the user in office 365 and set sps-hidefromaddresslists value in sharpeoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, user-profile-service, people-search

I want to deactivate some of my company users and also I want to exclude deactivate users from SharePoint's online search.

Answer (score 1):

You could deactivate the user from the Microsoft admin center Or Azure Active Directory. With this, The Internal Property "AccountEnabled" will be set as False.

[image]

However If these disabled users are already Synced via User profiles into sharepoint then it will be visible into sharepoint people search.

**SPS-HideFromAddressLists** is internal OOTB property which not editable and can only be set by the system with the user sync process. This property is not connected with "AccountEnabled" Property mentioned above.

Microsoft has already taken care of this exclusion in the modern search experience. If you use the classic search center then you have to include SPS-HideFromAddressLists:0 filter in your query.

Now the question is how to set "SPS-HideFromAddressLists" property. Below are the steps.

1. log in to Microsoft Admin Center (https://admin.microsoft.com/)  -> Click on Exchange Admin Center (Url - https://admin.exchange.microsoft.com/)

[image]

2. goto Mailboxes - > select one or more mailboxes and click Hide from the address list button on the toolbar

[image]

3. Click on Ok to Save
4. During the user profile sync "SPS-HideFromAddressLists" value will automatically be set to 1 and Once the SharePoint crawler runs it will not consider the user and the user will not appear in search results.

Answer (score 0):

This property is syncd from on-premise server and we can not edit it in online.

As a workaround, you can try to add a new profile property called hidefromsearch, boolean type, allow indexed in search settings,set this property on at least 1 user profile before it will be picked up by the crawl:
[image]

Wait for some time, create a new managed property that maps to the indexed crawled properties, and then update this attribute for disabled users.

Lastly, change the search query to exclude those disabled users, such as hidefromsearch not equals True.

More information:

https://thomasdaly.net/2016/01/16/hiding-people-from-people-search/